# Sending Object and app link over email ios

Tags: ios, email, core-data, swift

Hello everyone and thank you if you are able to help me.
I have an application that uses core data to store 'Game' Data. The main Model is made up of a few entities, one being 'Characters' and there are also relationships between entities.
What I would like to do is send an invitation to a game via email (I can already send an email from within the application), however I would like to include in the email :

- A means of opening the app if already on the device,
- if not then a link to the app store to download,
- and the specific 'character' that the host has chosen for the
  receiver.

When the app is opened by the receiver I would like it to add the 'Character' Object to a second Core data model.
The idea of this is to have two Models. One to hold Games that are full games and purchased by hosts and a second which holds only enough information to play the game as a Character.

I hope this is possible and thank you again for any help that you may be able to provide.

Comment: please send the code

Comment: I am unsure what code you would like... I have no idea about how to accomplish what I want in terms of sending the object and opening it in the app and so have not attempted that yet. However if you would like the general code for the whole app then I can post that this evening?

Comment: 'once you go to your lead'? Sorry I do not understand. Would you agree that the easiest way to do this is to create a CSV file of what I need to send and then turn it back into a managed object when the application is opened? If So then I believe that I can do this.

Comment: Ohhhh  NO your team Leader or your senior to discuss the model and come back , i am extremely sorry for inconvenience , i apologies my mistake .

Comment: Not to worry. I have no team leader. I am a project engineer for an engineering company... ios applications are a hobby of mine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If email is your preferred way to send an invitation to play - your best bet is to use a Custom Uri Scheme in your app.  It should cover options 1 & 3 option 2 is no brainer - The other details you want- adding character object to the second cordite etc. - those are things that you want to program once your app opens via the URI :

See this link for a complete tutorial:  http://iosdevelopertips.com/cocoa/launching-your-own-application-via-a-custom-url-scheme.html

PS your URI/ link would also work over SMS a QR Code maybe NFC once IOS opens it up.

Comment: Thank you! I agree that 2 is simple, and looking at the tutorial the other 2 don't seem too bad either. Just to make sure I am on the right page though am I right in thinking that along with the URL i would have to attach a file of some sort? i.e. a CSV version of my object?

Comment: Not really - just send the link and use parameters - MYAPP://parameter1 or MYAPP://?character='abc'&stage=20. - It should be possible to send csv files but it will just consume storage since you have to save the file then read it then delete it afterwards.  I'd use files for non text parameters - png. jpg. mp3 but other wise coding a long url is more efficient.

Comment: Yes that is brilliant. Using core data means that the app can already have all the data needed, by sending a query I can access the particular data needed. Thanks very much. I would rate the answer but I have not yet got enough reputation to do so. But thank you very much